# How to get database working when i install my project in other system

Tags: vb.net

Okay I have created my project in Visual Studio 2012 express edition. I have used ClickOnce Application deployment to create a setup file. Everything works absolutely fine when i run the project in my computer. But when i install the same project in another computer database connections are not working saying path is not correct. I understand that the path given to connect to the database is of my system. Now that is my problem and what should i do to make the database stuff to work in other systems as well? Please help me as this would make my project complete!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the application would be deployed with an app/web.config. Or another configuration file. Your code then reads the connection string out of this file to find the database.

On deployment, you can change the config file after deployment, this can be done manually, or in IIS if its a web config file, not sure on automatic editing with click once deployments; but a config file or setting of some kind would be key.

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer. I got the config file and it looks like this and i have no idea what to change: <add name="Virtuosic.My.MySettings.AdmindbConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Admindb.accdb" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />

Comment: Ok, looks like that is saying its expecting the database in the data directory of your app, are you deploying the database in the install?